# Finding the number of unique objects in an array in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Say I have a following array which contains the following objects:

```
array = [{name: 'foo', number: 1}, {name: 'foo', number: 1}, {name: 'bar', number: 1}]
```

How would I go about finding the number of `foo` in this array? I am currently doing

```
search(name, array) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].name=== name) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

I would like to be able to run the `search()` function and be able to get the number of objects which has name `foo` and the number of objects which has name `bar` instead of having to pass in the name of the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let array = [{
  name: 'foo',
  number: 1
}, {
  name: 'foo',
  number: 2
}, {
  name: 'bar',
  number: 1
}]

function count(input) {
  var output = {};

  array.forEach(item => {
    if (output[item.name]) {
      output[item.name] += item.number;
    } else {
      output[item.name] = item.number;
    }
  });

  return output;
}

var result = count(array);
console.log(result);
```

You can iterate over the items and add the counts for each name that is the same. Hope this is what you were looking for, otherwise let me know

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `filter` function

```js
let array = [{name: 'foo', number: 1}, {name: 'foo', number: 1}, {name: 'bar', number: 1}]

let count = array.filter(e => e.name === "foo").length;
console.log(count)
```